# i want to wrap the category name if it is too long

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light">
  <div class="tabs" style="margin-top: 1px;">
    <a class="tab-item" ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-class="{ active: isCategory(category) }"
          ng-click="categoryFunction(category,$index)">
          {{category.name}}
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want category name to be wraped if it is too long

Comment: You can either : Use css to hide the overflow part of the text https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow assuming that you have a fixed size in px for your tab-item. Or make your own angularjs filter that will wrap the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
{{ category.name | limitTo: 10 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

For wrapping the content you can use

```
white-space: normal;
```

or

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set fixed width and truncate any overflowing text like this

```
.tab-item {
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```